# If asked to provide separate list of publications in addition to CV, should CV still include list of publications?

Tags: application, cv

I am applying for an assisstant professor position, and asked to provide a CV, as well as a separate list of publications. Should I still keep a "publications" section in the CV, or refer to the separate list by writing something like "see enclosed list of publications"?

Comment: Even when asked for a separate list, I still keep the list in my CV whenever I apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I would say so.  A CV always should list publications.

It may be that for some reason to do with their search process, they find it convenient to have a separate document that only lists publications, rather than digging through the CV to find it.  But that doesn't mean you should remove this list from the CV.

Comment: When we put ads on mathjobs, sometimes we ask for a separate publication list, but I think this is mostly a function of whoever put the ad on mathjobs, rather than what people looking at files want.  Personally, I prefer to look at everything on the CV, and am annoyed when I have to look at the publication list separately.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning, that for certain grants, it does seem to be expected that the CV will not contain any publications (judging from length requirements that would make this basically impossible).

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on whether they put page limits on the documents. If they do, I would not waste pages on duplicating the publications but only list them in the separate publication document.
A reasonable compromise could be to list a short selection of your most recent or most important publications in the CV and then provide the full publication list in the separate document.